# Isekai manhwa in which the blonde female lead is confused as to what novel she's been reincarnated into

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I'm looking for historical isekai manhwa where the (female, blonde) main character is reincarnated into a novel, but she doesn't know which novel she's in.

Her fiancé is a hot villain that she thought was the original male lead in the novel. He had black hair.

I read it on Coffee Manga a few weeks ago. At that point, only a few chapters had been uploaded.

Comment: Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead and/or the male lead?

Comment: I read it in Coffeemanga few weeks ago. But because it doesn't have a lot of chapters, I'm thinking to marinate it for a long time yet i forgot to take note the tittleT_T

Comment: I think the hair of the fl is blonde while the ml is black.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[I Think I Have Transmigrated Somewhere](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/hutovsg/i-think-i-have-transmigrated-somewhere)***...?

> Even though the harsh reality feels like living as a beggar, to think that the end would be death from overworking!
>
> If it’s going to end like this, I should’ve been in a lot of relationships, but wait, oh my...
>
> Who are you in the mirror? I’m a little flustered but this body… It’s really pretty! **It feels like I’ve been transmigrated into a romance fantasy novel.**
>
> Since I’m already like this, should I enjoy the romance while I’m at it?
>
> **“But which novel did I get transmigrated into?”**
>
> I’ve read dozens of books where the ‘Northern Duke’ and ‘Childhood Friends’ exist, I’ve read so many with a black-haired male lead and a blonde female lead, Ah~ I don’t know!! For now, let’s start by conquering the male characters!
>
> “I already have a promised marriage."
>
> “I volunteered for the Western Guard. We won’t be able to meet for several years.”
>
> What is this, **is this really a romance fantasy novel? Why is everyone running away?! In the first place… was I really transmigrated as the female lead? What kind of novel is this!!!!**

The protagonist read dozens if not hundreds of romance fantasy novels before dying of overwork. She then woke up in another world as the blonde-haired Lady Elena Chavez, who's been arranged to marry the black-haired Duke of the North. The main thing troubling her is that while she believe she's been transmigrated into a novel, she can't figure out which novel it is.

> [image: "I Think I Have Transmigrated Somewhere," chapter 1, page 7.] [image: "I Think I Have Transmigrated Somewhere," chapter 1, page 18.]

This is a fairly new manhwa, first released in 2023 according to the Manga Updates page.

Comment: I appreciate your help so much. But, its not that one. That manhwa is first released in 2024, January.

Comment: If you're certain that it was first released in January 2024, that the female lead is blonde, and that you read it on Coffee Manga, you should be able to find it pretty easily by searching on the website itself. _I Think I Have Transmigrated Somewhere_ is definitely on there, the first chapter having been released in October 2023. I've yet to find another one with a blonde female lead and a synopsis that matches your description as closely.